# Contact Form Posting

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have created a html, php and js files for my Contact Form.
I upload it to my Hosting Provider just for testing as I don't have a live server.
When I fill out all required fields and hit Submit, I don't get information send to email address.
This is just a simple form so that customers can send me their query and details.

```js
$(function() {
  $(".form-control").on('focus', function() {
    $(this).parents(".form-group").addClass('focused');
  });
  $(".form-control").on('blur', function() {
    $(this).parents(".form-group").removeClass('focused');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <form action="form-handler.php" method="POST" class="form">

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="name" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="Name" placeholder="Jane Doe" tabindex="1" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="Email" placeholder="Jane@Doe.com" tabindex="2" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="subject" class="form-label">Subject</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" name="Subject" placeholder="Subject" tabindex="3" required>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="message" class="form-label">Message</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" cols="50" rows="5" placeholder="Write your message here..." tabindex="4"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="btn" type="submit">Send Message</button>
    </div>

  </form>
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

PHP

```php
<?php
$message_sent = false;
if (isset($_POST['email']) && $_POST['email'] != '')
{
    if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))
    {
        //submit the form
        $userName = $_POST['name'];
        $userEmail = $_POST['email'];
        $messageSubject = $_POST['subject'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $to = "...@....com";
        $body = "";

        $body = "From:" . $userName . "\r\n";
        $body = "Email:" . $userEmail . "\r\n";
        $body = "Message:" . $message . "\r\n";
        mail($to, $messageSubject, $body);
        $message_sent = true;
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Please enable PHP error reporting to see if you get any errors

Comment: what does browser show in network of developtool ?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Is this a JS problem, or a PHP problem?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is

```
$body = "From:" . $userName . "\r\n";
$body = "Email:" . $userEmail . "\r\n";
$body = "Message:" . $message . "\r\n";
mail($to, $messageSubject, $body);
```

And from documentation I saw that a correct way to send additional headers like FROM is the folloewing:

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Another more complete way is the following:

```
// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers[] = 'MIME-Version: 1.0';
$headers[] = 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1';

// Additional headers
$headers[] = 'To: Mary <mary@example.com>, Kelly <kelly@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'From: Birthday Reminder <birthday@example.com>';
$headers[] = 'Cc: birthdayarchive@example.com';
$headers[] = 'Bcc: birthdaycheck@example.com';

// Mail it
mail($to, $subject, $message, implode("\r\n", $headers));
```

Finally, .. instead of code this:

```
mail($to, $messageSubject, $body);
$message_sent = true;
```

You should code this

```
$message_sent = mail($to, $messageSubject, $body);
```

Because your code assumes all works fine but mail function already return true or false if mail is sent or not.

But the most important stuff I saw is that your form ha inputs named:

- Name
- Email
- Subject
- message

and your php code check for

- $_POST['name']; // different from Name
- $_POST['email']; // different from Email
- $_POST['subject']; // different rom Subject
- $_POST['message']; // ok

So, ... **if (filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))** should always return false because `$_POST['email']` email not exists.

Comment: The hole day I have tried what all have mentioned but for me no winning "I can SLAP myself" for not winning,, as this is new to me... Although, I have sort-off managed to get something to send me an email, BUT, not including the Information I require.

Comment: I will post gain of what I have done.

Comment: You can simply edit your question adding the update

Comment: thank you sensorario, I am trying to Update my Question but keep on getting the err of It seems it is mostly Code?????

Comment: Try to remove `    $headers = "message:" .$message. "\r\n";` from headers. You already sent the message in third parameter of mail() function.

Comment: Thank you sensorario, I have removed as mentioned, but still only get the "Subject" and "You have received a new notification from "whatever@whatever.com"

Comment: You have also checked that all html input names are exactly the same you get in $_POST variables?

Comment: here is my email address; freakinguser@hotmail.com ; send me an email, I will send you what I have done and please maybe you can help me as I am having some difficulties from this "site" to help me out. Like I said, I am VERY new to this CODING thing, reason I am ASKING for HELP...